# My app does not want to re-render, however the list in the context does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

Short story: I am making my own GIS (geographic information system) and want to be able to upload JSON files with geographical data. I do not however want to save files in a database, just in a list. Furthermore I'm using Context to send data to the  (leaflet) component. When I upload new JSONs to the layerList it gets updated but the  component does not re-render. I have console logged the list after uploading files and the all get added.

The use of context is based off of DevEd's guide on context from youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o&t=1352s

Here is my code

Context:

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "../../App.css";


export const FileContext = createContext()

export const FileProvider = (props) => {

    const [layerList, setLayerList] = useState('');

   return(
        <FileContext.Provider value = {[layerList, setLayerList]}>
            {props.children}
        </FileContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Upload component:

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useState} from 'react';
import "../../App.css";
import {FileContext} from './FileContext'


function FileUpload() {

    const  [layerList, setLayerList]  = useContext(FileContext)

    const onFileChange = e => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
        fileReader.onload = e => {
            setLayerList(prevLayer => [...prevLayer, JSON.parse(e.target.result)]);
        };
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div id='fileupload'>
                <input type="file" onChange={onFileChange} />
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default FileUpload;
```

Map:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, GeoJSON} from 'react-leaflet'
import "../App.css";
import { FileContext } from '../LandingPage/ToolbarComponents/FileContext';
import data from '../Layers/layer1.json'
import data1 from '../Layers/layer2.json'



function MapOslo() {

  const [layerList] = useContext(FileContext)

  return (
      <Map center={[59.93, 10.75]} zoom={1}>
          <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <GeoJSON data={layerList} style={['color','#006400']} />
      </Map>
  );
}

export default MapOslo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I pulled your repo and I think it's solved now. Notice how the map.js component it's logging the data from the updated .json file. Your map.js component should look like the following:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, GeoJSON} from 'react-leaflet'
import "../App.css";
import { FileContext } from ../LandingPage/ToolbarComponents/FileContext';
import data from '../Layers/layer1.json'
import data1 from '../Layers/layer2.json'

function MapOslo() {

const [layerList] = useContext(FileContext);

const [layerState, setLayerState] = useState(layerList);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLayerState(layerList);
    console.log(layerState);
  });

  return (
      <Map center={[59.93, 10.75]} zoom={1}>
          <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <GeoJSON data={layerState} style={['color','#006400']} />
      </Map>
  );
}

export default MapOslo;
```

EDIT 2: I'm not sure what do you mean by the layers... but it's showing the marker now with the static position you previously included in there. See below updated map.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, GeoJSON, Marker, Popup} from 'react-leaflet'
import "../App.css";
import { FileContext } from '../LandingPage/ToolbarComponents/FileContext';
import data from '../Layers/layer1.json'
import data1 from '../Layers/layer2.json'



function MapOslo() {

  const [layerList] = useContext(FileContext);

  const [layerState, setLayerState] = useState(layerList);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLayerState(layerList);
    console.log(layerState);
  });

  const position = [59.93, 10.75];

  return (
      <Map center={position} zoom={6}>
          <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <GeoJSON data={layerState} style={['color','#006400']} />
          <Marker position={position}>
            <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
          </Marker>
      </Map>
  );
}

export default MapOslo;
```

Comment: Not really I get an 'object is not iterable' error. 
The reason why you can't replicate the code is because I have just linked the context parts of the project, if you want you can check out the entierty of it on my github.
https://github.com/martinwe001/programming-in-geo

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look. I'm quite sure it will be related with the useEffect Hook if the component it's not re-rendering.

Comment: Just edited the first answer with the tweaked map.js component.

Comment: Thank you so much, I cant believe you took your time to do that. However the map still renders without the layers. Did you manage to get the layers to render when you tried?

Comment: no worries! it also helps me improve my React skills. Just updated the answer again! I leave it to you now to figure it out how to make the position dynamic by getting the location from your uploaded files, I guess? Please upvote if that was of a help for you.

Comment: The JSONs contain layers (term used in geomatics to describe points and areas on a map), and it was the layers from the files themself I wanted to show in the map

Comment: The layers provided in the repo itself contains lines, areas and points. These are the files I have been trying to upload and display on the map

Comment: ok, I got it. Then you should create components like the marker and pass the properties that you need from the layerState array of objects. Not sure if leafleft provides those elements or you will have to create them from scratch. You have now the updated data on the state to achieve that. Good luck!

Comment: this thread might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750598/what-is-the-good-way-to-create-custom-geojson-component?rq=1